# How do I execute a seria of commands with execa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

I'm working on a node script that will do some stuff with `execa` package.
Basically I want that script to change directory to certain path and then run another command within that path.

I did it like that:

```
execa.command('cd /some/dir && pwd');
```

But `pwd` command won't execute for some reason, though it finishes successfully.

What could be the reason, the command after `&&` won't execute, and is there any other way to manage that task?

Thanks!

Comment: [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa) say: "The shell option must be used if the command uses shell-specific features, as opposed to being a simple file followed by its arguments." I'm guessing `&&` might be considered a shell-specific feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question you should be asking is "How do I run a command with a different working directory?", which will give you the simple, robust, cross-platform solution of using the `cwd` option:

```
execa.command('pwd', { cwd: '/some/dir' });
```

If you instead want to accomplish this task with `&&`, you can do that by invoking a shell. This is more fragile and platform specific:

```
execa('sh', ['-c', 'cd /some/dir && pwd']);
```